# Is there an R function that change decimal points at metaprop in forest plot?

Tags: r, decimal, percentage

I tried to change the decimal scales on my forest plot by using "decimal" function. However, the decimal function is not working.

My code is as below:

```
forest(metaprop(c(23,89),c(28,126),pscale=100, digits=1, studlab=c("A","B"), level=0.95, level.comb=0.95, comb.random=F, sm="PFT",rma="REML"))
```

I designed it to show **percentages(XX%)** instead of rate(0.XX), **but problem is it expose second decimal scales of percentage**. I want to show just first decimal scale or not(XX.X% or XX%).

Please give me advise for it.